# in_array not finding value in array

Tags: php, arrays, output

I have an array formed by exploding a string as follows.

```
$interest_array = explode(',', $user->interests);
```

When I var_dump this array I get

```
array(3) { 
    [0]=> string(19) "Acute critical care" 
    [1]=> string(11) " Cardiology" 
    [2]=> string(20) " Computed Tomography"
}
```

With the following code

```
if (in_array('Acute critical care', $interest_array)) {
        echo "selected";}
```

I output....selected. 
Now thats fine, but I need this to work for several of the array values. With the following code for example,

```
if (in_array('Acute critical care', $interest_array)) {
    echo "selected_once";
}

if (in_array('Cardiology', $interest_array)) {
    echo "selected_twice";
}
```

I only get one output of `selected once`, but I am expecting  an output of  `selected once` **twice**.

Why is this. I have seen that many people have had similar issues with in_array but none of the solutions I have found work (and most of the questions are slightly different. I have tried flipping the array and using `array_key_exists` without luck. I have also tried `preg_replace` to remove the white space within the string without luck. Can someone explain what the issue is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look the `var_dump()` output carefully, you can see that the string `Cardiology`has a space at the beginning:

```
string(11) " Cardiology"
            ^
```

This is causing [`in_array()`](http://php.net/in_array) to not detect it as a matching value. To remove the space, you could apply `trim` on all the array elements using [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map) before doing the `in_array()` check:

```
$interest_array = explode(',', $user->interests);
$interest_array = array_map('trim', $interest_array);
```

Comment: @GhostRider: Glad I could be of help. Cheers!